# Connect Android Activity with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, android-activity, request, spreadsheet

I would like to make a call of my method class , which allows me to question my worksheet.
Now I would like to know how to call my function of DataAccess class , when I click the button enters LoginActivity to query my worksheet.
DataAccess class is up and running.

This method of my class DataAcces (I tested it and works correctly):

```
    public boolean checkUser(String username,String password) throws IOException,ServiceException{

     SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MyApp");
     FeedURLFactory factory = FeedURLFactory.getDefault();
     String key = "***my_key***";
     URL spreadSheetUrl = factory.getWorksheetFeedUrl(key,"public","full");
     WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(spreadSheetUrl, WorksheetFeed.class);

     WorksheetEntry worksheet = feed.getEntries().get(0);
     URL url = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
     ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(url,ListFeed.class);

     List<ListEntry> l = listFeed.getEntries();
     for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
         String user = l.get(j).getCustomElements().getValue("username");
         String pwd = l.get(j).getCustomElements().getValue("password");
         if(user.equals(username) && pwd.equals(password))
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
    return false;
 }
```

This is method that I call in `signInButton.setOnClickListener` :

```
private void signIn(String username,String password) {
 DataAcces dataAccess = new DataAccess();
 if(dataAccess.checkUser(username,password);){
    System.out.println("ok");
 }
}
```

When I call `dataAccess.checkUser(username,password)` I get **FATAL ERROR**

PLEASE HELP ME!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but in this line you have:

```
if(dataAccess.checkUser(username,password);){
```

Try the following

```
if(dataAccess.checkUser(username,password)){
```